# Dereferencing a double pointer

Tags: c

I have code snippet that I can't understand how it works, because of one line that does a double dereference. The code looks like this:

```
void afunction(int**x){
    *x = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    **x = 12;
    *(*x + 1) = 13;
}

int main(){
    int *v = 10;
    afunction(&v);

    printf("%d %d\n", v[0], v[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

I understand that the first element of the pointer to pointer gets the value 12, but the line after that I just can't seem to understand. Does the second element in the first pointer get value 13?

Comment: so what does your output tell you?

Comment: This code results in a runtime error

Comment: Inside the function, `x` has type `int **`.  Therefore `*x` has type `int *`, and `*x + 1` is pointer arithmetic: the result is a pointer to one *element* past `**x`.  `*(*x + 1)` designates the `int` at that position; it is by definition exactly equivalent to `(*x)[1]`.  So yes, the last line of the function sets the second `int` in the dynamically allocated block to 13.

Comment: @m_callens, it does not (except that v isn't free'd). There is a compile time error that theere is an erroneous initialization of v in main.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Assuming a moder OS it is freed by system.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie hmm, [ran here](http://ideone.com/dN2Lxx) give output as well as runtime error

Comment: @m_callens where is the runtime error?...

Comment: @m_callens Well; I see: it is due to return 1 in main.

Comment: ... and ideone is unusual in classifying that as a runtime error.

Comment: In any case, the phrasing of your question suggests a possible misunderstanding: the memory to which a pointer points is not "in" or in any way part of that pointer.  A pointer does not have elements, only a single value, but that value may point to a space that accommodates one or more objects of the pointer's target type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is rather easy to understand if you use a temporary variable, eg:

```
void afunction(int**x)
{
    int* t = *x;

    t = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    *t = 12;
    *(t+1) = 13;
}
```

so:

- `x` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`
- `*x` yields a `int*` (pointer to `int`)
- `**x =` is like `*(*x) =` so you first obtain the pointer to `int` then by dereferencing you are able to set the value at the address

The last part `*(*x+1) =` can be broken down:

```
int* pointerToIntArray = *x;
int* secondElementInArray = pointerToIntArray + 1;
*secondElementInArray = 13;
```

The purpose of using a pointer to pointer here is that you can pass the address to an `int*` to the function and let the function allocate the memory and fill it with data. The same purpose could be done by returning an `int*`, eg:

```
int* afunction() {
  int* x = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
  *x = 12;
  *(x+1) = 13;
  return x;
}

int main() {
  int* v = afunction();
  return 0;
}
```