# Misunderstanding in particular user case of pointers and double-pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, double-pointer

I'm dealing with pointers, double-pointers and arrays, and I think I'm messing up a bit my mind. I've been reading about it, but my particular user-case is messing me up, and I'd appreciate if someone could clear a bit my mind. This is a small piece of code I've built to show my misunderstanding:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void fnFindValue_vo(uint8_t *vF_pu8Msg, uint8_t vF_u8Length, uint8_t **vF_ppu8Match, uint8_t vF_u8Value)
{
    for(int i=0; i<vF_u8Length; i++)
    {
        if(vF_u8Value == vF_pu8Msg[i])
        {
            *vF_ppu8Match = &vF_pu8Msg[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t u8Array[]={0,0,0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64};
    uint8_t *pu8Reference = &u8Array[3];
    
    /*
     * Purpose: Find the index of a value in u8Array from a reference
     * Reference: First non-zero value
     * Condition: using the function with those input arguments
     */

    // WAY 1
    uint8_t *pu8P2 = &u8Array[0];
    uint8_t **ppu8P2 = &pu8P2;
    fnFindValue_vo(u8Array,10,ppu8P2,16); // Should be diff=4
    uint8_t u8Diff1 = *ppu8P2 - pu8Reference;
    printf("Diff1: %u\n", u8Diff1);
    
    // WAY 2
    uint8_t* ppu8Pos; // Why this does not need to be initialized and ppu8P2 yes
    fnFindValue_vo(u8Array,10,&ppu8Pos,64); // Should be diff=6
    uint8_t u8Diff2 = ppu8Pos - pu8Reference;
    printf("Diff2: %u\n", u8Diff2);
}
```

Suppose the function `fnFindValue_vo` and its arguments cannot be changed. So my purpose is to find the relative index of a value in the array taking as reference the first non-zero value (no need to find it, can be hard-coded).

In the first way, I've done it following my logic and understanding of the pointers. So I have `*pu8P2` that contains the address of the first member of `u8Array`, and `**ppu8P2` containing the address of `pu8P2`. So after calling the funcion, I just need to substract the pointers 'pointing' to `u8Array` to get the relative index.

Anyway, I tried another method. I just created a pointer, and passed it's address, without initializing the pointer, to the funcion. So later I just need to substract those two pointers and I get also the relative index.

My confusion comes with this second method.

- Why `ppu8Pos` does not have to be initialized, and `ppu8P2` yes? I.e. Why couldn't I declare it as `uint8_t **ppu8P2;`? (it gives me Segmentation fault).
- Which of the two methods is more practical/better practice for coding?
- Why is it possible to give the address to a pointer when the function's argument is a double pointer?

Comment: I recommend you draw your array and the pointers using pencil and paper. Draw the array as a long rectangle, divided into squares (one for each element). Then draw a square for e.g. `puBP2` and from it draw an arrow to element `0` in the "array". Then draw a new square for `ppuB2` and draw an arrow from it to the square for `puBP2`. Do the same for all other pointers you might have. And remember, when you dereference a pointer (use the unary `*` operator on it) you follow the arrow to where it points.

Comment: The problem is not much related to where the pointers are pointing and it's content, but more about differences between them, as I point the 3 misunderstandings at the end of the post. I've drawn both cases, and I understand they both give the correct answer, but I cannot still answer the last 3 points by drawing it. Thanks anyway for the point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why ppu8Pos does not have to be initialized, and ppu8P2 yes

You are not using the value of `ppu8Pos` right away. Instead, you pass its address to another function, where it gets assigned by-reference. On the other hand, `ppu8P2`  *is* the address of `ppu8Pos` you pass to another function, where its value is used, so you need to initialise it.

> Which of the two methods is more practical/better practice for coding

They are identical for all intents and purposes, for exactly the same reason these two fragments are identical:

```
// 1
double t = sin(x)/cos(x);

// 2
double s = sin(x), c = cos(x);
double t = s/c;
```

In one case, you use a variable initialised to a value. In the other case, you use a value directly. The type of the value doesn't really matter. It could be a double, or a pointer, or a pointer to a pointer.

> Why is it possible to give the address to a pointer when the function's argument is a double pointer?

These two things you mention, an address to a pointer and a double pointer, are one and the same thing. They are not two very similar things, or virtually indistinguishable, or any weak formulation like that. No, the two wordings mean exactly the same, to all digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

The address of a pointer (like e.g. `&pu8P2`) is a *pointer to a pointer*.

The result of `&pu8P2` is a pointer to the variable `pu8P2`.

And since `pu8P2` is of the type `uint8_t *` then a pointer to such a type must be `uint8_t **`.

---

Regarding `ppu8Pos`, it doesn't need to be initialized, because that happens in the `fnFindValue_vo` function with the assignment `*vF_ppu8Match = &vF_pu8Msg[i]`.

***But*** there is a trap here: If the condition `vF_u8Value == vF_pu8Msg[i]` is never true then the assignment never happens and `ppu8Pos` will remain uninitialized. So that initialization of `ppu8Pos` is really needed after all.

---

The "practicality" of each solution is more an issue of personal opinion I believe, so I leave that unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function `fnFindValue_vo` can be a reason of undefined behavior because it does not set the pointer `*vF_ppu8Match` in case when the target value is not found in the array.

Also it is very strange that the size of the array is specified by an object of the type `uint8_t`. This does not make a sense.

The function should be declared at least the following way

```
void fnFindValue_vo( const uint8_t *vF_pu8Msg, size_t vF_u8Length, uint8_t **vF_ppu8Match, uint8_t vF_u8Value )
{
    const uint8_t *p = vF_pu8Msg;

    while ( p != vF_pu8Msg + vF_u8Length && *p != vF_u8Value ) ++p;

    *vF_ppu8Match = ( uint8_t * )p;
}
```

The difference between the two approaches used in your question is that in the first code snippet if the target element will not be found then the pointer will still point to the first element of the array

```
uint8_t *pu8P2 = &u8Array[0];
```

And this expression

```
 uint8_t u8Diff1 = *ppu8P2 - pu8Reference;
```

will yield some confusing positive value (due to the type `uint8_t`) because the difference `*ppu8P2 - pu8Reference` be negative.

In the second code snippet in this case you will get undefined behavior due to this statement

```
uint8_t u8Diff2 = ppu8Pos - pu8Reference;
```

because the pointer ppu8Pos was not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, not trying to understand your code completely, but my advice is do not overcomplicate it.

I would start with one fact which helped me untangle:

if you have `int a[10]`; then a is a pointer, in fact
`int x = a[2]` is exactly the same like `int x = *(a+2)` - you can try it.

So let's have

```
int a[10]; //this is an array 
//a is a pointer to the begging of the array
a[2] is an int type and it is the third value in that array stored at memory location a plus size of two ints;
&a[2] is a pointer to that third value

*(a) is the first value in the array a
*(a+1) is the same as a[1] and it is the second int value in array a

and finally
**a is the same as *(*a) which means: *a is take the first int value in the array a (the same as above) and the second asterisk means "and take that int and pretend it is a pointer and take the value from the that location" - which is most likely a garbage.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118190/dereferencing-a-double-pointer

Only when you have a[5][5]; then a[0] would be still a pointer to the first row and a[1] would be a pointer to the second row and **(a) would then be the same as a[0][0]. 

https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/2d-arrays-in-c-example/
```

Drawing it on paper as suggested in comments helps, but what helped me a lot is to learn using debugger and break points. Put a breakpoint at the first line and then go trough the program step by step. In the "watches" put all variants like
`pu8P2`,`&pu8P2`,`*pu8P2`,`**pu8P2` and see what is going on.